# Почему каждый раз перерисовываются контролы

Tags: c#, winforms

Я первый раз пишу UI и не могу понять, как работает рендеринг контролов и как сделать так, чтобы нарисованный один раз контрол не перерисовывался каждый раз.
Ниже минимальный пример, который должен объяснить, что я хочу и что у меня не получается.
Также добавил gif, который наглядно иллюстрирует проблему (по клику на ноду таблицы перерисовываются каждый раз).

Я пробовал несколько вариантов реализации - во всех одинаковая проблема.
В той реализации, которую вы можете наблюдать ниже, на главной форме есть TreeView, Tab Page и кнопка Load.
Для каждой ноды в Tree View создается свой Flow Panel (с Visible = false по умолчанию). Каждый Flow Panel добавляется в Tab Page. По нажатию на кнопку Load я хочу добавить в Flow Panel каждой ноды какие-то таблицы.
Главная форма хранит ссылку на ActiveFlow - тот FlowPanel, который я хочу видеть на Tab Page.
По клику на ноду в дереве я хочу видеть таблицы, соответствующие выбранной ноде - я беру Flow Panel выбранной ноды и выставлю для него Visible = true.
Кнопка Load здесь служит заменой "загрузки" программы.

Проблема:
После клика по ноде в дереве, таблицы каждый раз перерисовываются. Я не понимаю почему и как это прекратить.
В данном случае это не так бросается в глаза, но в боевом примере у меня вместо таблиц custom control, который, видимо, намного тяжелее и рисуется дольше.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что я делаю не так и как это исправить.

**Node**

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace AppTest2
{
    public class SuperNode : TreeNode
    {
        public FlowLayoutPanel FlowView { get; }
 
        public SuperNode(String name) : base()
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Text = name;
 
            this.FlowView = new FlowLayoutPanel()
            {
                Visible = false,
 
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Form:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace AppTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();
 
        public FlowLayoutPanel ActiveFlow { get; internal set; } = null;
 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            for (var idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
            {
                var name = "node" + idx.ToString();
                var node = new SuperNode(name);
                this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
 
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(node.FlowView);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (SuperNode node in this.treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                for (var idx = 0; idx < this.random.Next(5, 10); idx++)
                {
                    var randomTable = this.GetRandomTable();
 
                    node.FlowView.Controls.Add(randomTable);   
                }
            }
        }
 
        private TableLayoutPanel GetRandomTable()
        {
            var table = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single,
                RowCount = this.random.Next(5, 10),
                ColumnCount = this.random.Next(5, 10),
 
                AutoSize = true
            };
 
            for (var column = 0; column < table.ColumnCount; column++)
            {
                for (var row = 0; row < table.RowCount; row++)
                {
                    var label = new Label()
                    {
                        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                        Text = column.ToString() + row.ToString()
                    };
 
                    table.Controls.Add(label);
                }
            }
 
            return table;
        }
 
        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.treeView1.SelectedNode != e.Node)
            {
                if (this.ActiveFlow != null)
                    this.ActiveFlow.Visible = false;
 
                this.ActiveFlow = (e.Node as SuperNode).FlowView;
                this.ActiveFlow.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Form Designer**

```cs
namespace AppTest2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
 
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.treeView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
            this.buttonLoad = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // treeView1
            // 
            this.treeView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 87);
            this.treeView1.Name = "treeView1";
            this.treeView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(212, 441);
            this.treeView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.treeView1.NodeMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.treeView1_NodeMouseClick);
            // 
            // buttonLoad
            // 
            this.buttonLoad.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.buttonLoad.Name = "buttonLoad";
            this.buttonLoad.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(211, 53);
            this.buttonLoad.TabIndex = 1;
            this.buttonLoad.Text = "Load";
            this.buttonLoad.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonLoad.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonLoad_Click);
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
            this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 0);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1074, 821);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1066, 795);
            this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1304, 821);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.buttonLoad);
            this.Controls.Add(this.treeView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
 
        }
 
        #endregion
 
        private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonLoad;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
    }
}
```

[image: Так выглядит прорисовка таблиц в моем примере]

Comment: Если вам помог один из ответов, пожалуйста отметьте принятым наиболее полезный из них.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что для контролов в памяти не хранится никакая "картинка", системное API устроено таким образом, что они при необходимости рисуются в предоставленном контексте. Контрол стал видимым - контрол начал рисоваться.

Если вас не устраивает постепенное появление контролов - можете попробовать по-играться со свойством [DoubleBuffered](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netcore-3.1).

Если же вас волнует именно скорость отрисовки - попробуйте рисовать свой пользовательский контрол заранее, на Bitmap, а в событии Paint выводить на экран уже этот Bitmap.